# Nginx web server on VPS over HTTP - hsts

Tags: nginx, http, hsts

So I have been trying to serve a simple static web page over HTTP using Nginx 1.14.0 (Ubuntu). I am able to: `curl` the web page using both domain name and IP-address
and find the web page in browser using IP-address.

But I *can't* load the web page in a **browser** via domain name (timeout). I have tried Chrome and Firefox on different devices/networks and have repeatedly emptied web and DNS caches. DNS for my domain is correctly configured via my registrar.

I eventually set up HTTPS and it now works, but I am completely stumped as to why the site timed out over HTTP. It would seem drastic if Firefox and Chrome have started forcing everything to HTTPS. I haven't heard or have been able to find anything about this in my searches online. It would be great if someone else has any insight on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what the problem was as I was writing the question. Firefox and Chrome are forcing redirects to https on `dev.` domains specifically. Found it in [this article by Mattias Geniar](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

I am using a `dev.` domain. :)